# Why is this not an error in Java Generics

Tags: java, generics

In generics, we are not supposed to create an array of generic type. But however, this type of generic array is supported.

```
List<?> list[] = {};
```

Why isn't this an error / why is it supported?

Comment: Have you tried it? Who told you so (hint: that guy is messing with you)? My Eclipse told me otherwise.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei: Yes, I tried. We are able to create such a reference.

Comment: There are no arrays created in that code...

Comment: Post the code, then, but I cannot.

Comment: @jahroy: I am sorry. I made the edits now. Apologies.

Comment: It cannot be parameterized with arguments <?> !!!

Comment: This is actually given in effective java

Comment: Your version has a typo maybe. Which page?

Comment: @ZiyaoWei: At page 191. Item 41

Comment: No it's not. That page doesn't even have a `=`. What are you reading?

Comment: Now that the original code has been edited, this code DOES work for me.  I don't see what the question is, though.  Your code creates an array of Lists of objects.

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying. The edit did not reflect until refresh, so my apologies. This is still nearly a non-question, though.

Comment: `new List<?>[42]` is perfectly legal in Java. Only when the parameter is not `?` that it is not allowed.

Answer (score 4):

This declaration defines an empty array of `List` objects containing an unknown type.